# SELECT MIN and MAX of column1 by another distinct column2 and fetch entire row

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, min

Ok, so I have the table `Television` that has over 1,000 records and looks like this:

```
ID     Code    Source   Brand       Price
-----------------------------------------
930    A584    C11      Panasonic   512
843    VG873   U19      Sony        590
301    A584    J63      Panasonic   494
738    D900    T32      Samsung     378
786    VG873   Y91      Sony        575
409    E764    G48      LG          435
912    VG873   Y91      Sony        535
626    E764    H14      LG          460
581    E764    C55      LG          455
557    D900    I42      Samsung     390
```

I'm trying to run a query that would fetch the lowest price from each distinct brand where price is greater than or equal to $400, fetching the entire row. The result on the above example set should look like this:

```
ID     Code    Source   Brand       Price
-----------------------------------------
301    A584    J63      Panasonic   494
409    E764    G48      LG          435
912    VG873   Y91      Sony        535
```

I tried some answers of somewhat similar questions in here but the results were off by a mile. The last I tried is the following and it was the closest but still not giving the desired result:

```
SELECT tv.* FROM Television tv
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Brand, MIN(Price) AS MinPrice 
    FROM Television
    GROUP BY Brand) groupedTV
ON tv.Brand= groupedTV.Brand
AND tv.Price= groupedTV.MinPrice
WHERE tv.Price>=400
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Corrected the result set (ID 301 should be the lowest in Panasonic). Thanks to @wilfo.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close, but you need the `where` clause in the subquery:

```
SELECT tv.*
FROM Television tv INNER JOIN
     (SELECT tv.Brand, MIN(Price) AS MinPrice 
      FROM Television tv
      WHERE tv.Price >= 400
      GROUP BY tv.Brand
     ) groupedTV
     ON tv.Brand = groupedTV.Brand AND
        tv.Price = groupedTV.MinPrice;
```

Comment: Thanks but it throws the error "Unknown column 'tv.Price' in 'where clause"

Answer (score 0):

From your example, shouldn't the Panasonic line be the row with id `301`?

In regards to a way to solution, when using `GROUP BY`, you have certain `SQL` expressions at your disposal. Specifically, try reading about `HAVING`

I would go with:

```
SELECT id, brand, price, min(price) FROM Television tv
GROUP by brand
HAVING price >= 400
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT brand
        FROM    television
        ) td
JOIN    television t
ON      t.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    television ti
        WHERE   ti.brand = td.brand
                AND ti.price >= 400
        ORDER BY
                ti.brand, ti.price
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `television (brand, price)` for this to work fast.